# Table view cell information resetting when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, uitableview

I am currently using a table view to display a menu, in which people can click on the `add` or `subtract` buttons to increase/decrease their order.

This table view has approximately 30 items and so you have to scroll down to get to all the menu items. The problem is, when you scroll down, the table view cells above the scroll (that are now hidden) lose the data that they have just contained.

For example, if you have a menu item that you have ordered 2 of an item, that `2` on the label has now turned back to `0`. This is very object oriented so I am not sure why this is happening.

My table view class:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var appetizerTableView: UITableView!


var appetizerList = [OrderModel]()

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    appetizerTableView.delegate = self
    appetizerTableView.dataSource = self


    ref.child("Broadway").child("AppetizerDishes").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("WILL: \(snap)")
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = OrderModel(postkey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.appetizerList.append(post)
                }
            }
        }

        self.appetizerTableView.reloadData()
    })


}

var data=[OrderModel]()

func addButtonAction(addedList:[String:Float]) {
    print("WILLCOHEN:\(addedList)")
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return appetizerList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = appetizerList[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = appetizerTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell") as? OrderCell{
        cell.configureCell(post)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        return OrderCell()
    }
  }

}
```

My cell model class:

```
class OrderModel {
private var _dishName: String!
private var _dishDescription: String!
private var _numberOfOrders: Int!
private var _postKey: String!
private var _dishPrice: Float!

var dishName: String {
        return _dishName
}

var dishDescription: String {
    return _dishDescription
}

var numberOfOrders: Int {
    get {
        return _numberOfOrders
    }
    set (newVal) {
        _numberOfOrders = newVal
    }
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}

var dishPrice: Float {
    return _dishPrice
}

init(dishName: String, dishDescription: String, numberOfOrders: Int) {
    self._dishName = dishName
    self._dishDescription = dishDescription
}

init(postkey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    self._postKey = postkey

    if let dishName = postData["dishName"] as? String {
        self._dishName = dishName
    }

    if let dishDescription = postData["dishDescription"] as? String {
        self._dishDescription = dishDescription
    }

    if let numberOfOrders = postData["anumberOfOrders"] as? Int {
        self._numberOfOrders = numberOfOrders
    }

    if let dishPrice = postData["dishPrice"] as? Float32 {
        self._dishPrice = dishPrice
    }

}

}
```

My cell class:

```
protocol ClassNameDelegate:class {
func addButtonAction(addedList:[String:Float])
}

  var addedList: [String:Float] = [:]

 class OrderCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

var post: OrderModel!
var link: Link!




@IBOutlet weak var dishName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dishDescriptionAndPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfOrders: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addOrderBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var subtractOderBtn: UIButton!


weak var delegate: ClassNameDelegate?

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if post.numberOfOrders == 9 {
        numberOfOrders.text = "9"
    } else {
        if addedList[post.dishName] != nil {
            addedList[post.dishName] = post.dishPrice
        } else {
            addedList["\(post.dishName) \(Int(numberOfOrders.text!)! + 1)"] = post.dishPrice
        }
        post.numberOfOrders = post.numberOfOrders - 1
        numberOfOrders.text = "\(post.numberOfOrders)"
    }

    if delegate != nil {
        delegate?.addButtonAction(addedList)
    }
}

@IBAction func subtractButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if post.numberOfOrders == 0 {
        numberOfOrders.text = "0"
    } else {
        post.numberOfOrders = post.numberOfOrders + 1
        numberOfOrders.text = "\(post.numberOfOrders)"
    }
}

func getOrders() -> Dictionary<String, Float> {
    return addedList
}


func configureCell(post: OrderModel) {
        self.post = post
        self.dishName.text = post.dishName
        self.dishDescriptionAndPrice.text = post.dishDescription
        self.numberOfOrders.text = "0"

}
```

}

I should mention that I am pulling my table view data from Firebase.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: self.appetizerTableView.reloadData() write this line in if condition. and check your output.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `configureCell(post:)` on every cell, and in the `configureCell(post:)` function you set the text value of the `numbersOfOrders` label to `"0"`.  You should probably set the text to a value in the `OrderModel`/`post` argument.

Also, you should be sure to always call `configureCell(post:)` (you are not calling it if you have to manually create an `OrderCell`), so your `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` function should look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = appetizerList[indexPath.row]
    let cell = appetizerTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell") as? OrderCell ?? OrderCell()

    cell.configureCell(post)
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```